# Wait data from parent

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I know this is a frequent question, but the solution I saw in several questions is not working for me.

I have a child with an `@Input` that receives data from parent, but the data comes from an observable so it is async.

I read that an `*ngIf="data"` could solve my problem, but something it works and other times I get `undefined`

parent.Html

```
<div *ngIf="submittedBy">
    <app-q-sub-subsequent-process [(confirm)]="confirm" [(submittedBy)]="submittedBy"
        [createProjectSubResponseFunction]="createProjectSubResponseFunction">
    </app-q-sub-subsequent-process>
</div>}
```

parent.ts

```
submittedBy: any = [{fisrtName:"", lastName:"", organization: ""}];
ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.GetData().subscribe( response =>{
        this.submittedBy = response
    });
}
```

child.ts

```
@Input('submittedBy') submittedBy : any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.GetReviewerTypes().subscribe(response => {
        this.reviewerTypes = response;
        let user = {
            reviewerType: {
                reviewType:'', 
                reviewerTypeId: this.submittedBy.userTypeId
            }, 
            reviewer: {
                userId: this.submittedBy.id,
                user: `${this.submittedBy.lastName}, ${this.submittedBy.firstName}`
            }
        }
         /////////////This is where i get the error since user since 
         /////////////find returns undefiend because 
         /////////////user.reviewerType.reviewerTypeId = undefined
         user.reviewerType.reviewType = this.reviewerTypes.find(x => x.id = 
             user.reviewerType.reviewerTypeId).reviewType;
         let reviewerToAdd = { reviewerType: user.reviewerType, reviewer: user.reviewer }
         this.reviewersAdded = [{ ...reviewerToAdd }];
    },
         error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

The response in the child it's an array like this:

```
[
    {id:1, reviewType:'someType1'}
    {id:2, reviewType:'someType2'}
]
```

Sometimes I get the user in my child and other times I get `undefined` and an error `Cannot read property 'reviewType' of undefined`

I've also tried to catch the changes on `ngOnChanges()` but it never entered there.

I just tried with a setter:

child.ts

```
_submittedBy: any;
@Input('submittedBy') set submittedBy(value){
    this._submittedBy = value
};
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.GetReviewerTypes().subscribe(response => {
        this.reviewerTypes = response;
        let user = {
            reviewerType: {
                reviewType:'', 
                reviewerTypeId: this._submittedBy.userTypeId
            }, 
            reviewer: {
                userId: this._submittedBy.id,
                user: `${this._submittedBy.lastName}, ${this._submittedBy.firstName}`
            }
        }
         user.reviewerType.reviewType = this.reviewerTypes.find(x => x.id = 
             user.reviewerType.reviewerTypeId).reviewType;
         let reviewerToAdd = { reviewerType: user.reviewerType, reviewer: user.reviewer }
         this.reviewersAdded = [{ ...reviewerToAdd }];
    },
         error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire code? Why do you have two-way binding [(submittedBy)] if you only pass the value to the Input?

Comment: BTW, if you get `user.reviewerType.reviewerTypeId === undefined` then it means `this.submittedBy.userTypeId === undefined`. So `submittedBy` is set, just one of its property is undefined. Can you put a debug log in the parent to show the contents of `response`?

Comment: I am saying that perhaps the response sometimes does not include `userTypeId` field. Can you check that? Also please provide the exact error message you get.

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek I checked in the `*ngIf="submittedBy.firstName"` and it's working now, like you said `submittedBy` is set but `firstName` it's the one undefined

Comment: So is it working now or not or do you still have a problem?

Comment: @ŁukaszNojek it's working now with that change, thanks

Comment: You actually want `*ngIf="!!(data | async)"` if you want `data` to actually be resolved first. Just doing `*ngIf="data"` will be `true` once the observable is set.

Comment: @mwilson I tried that but got an error `cannot have a pipe in an action expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use asyn await in child component hope it helps

```
child.ts
    @Input('submittedBy') submittedBy : any;
    public data;
    async ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.submittedBy) {
          this.data = await this.submittedBy;
    }
    }
```

Html

```
   <div *ngIf="data">
        <app-q-sub-subsequent-process [(confirm)]="confirm" [(submittedBy)]="submittedBy"
            [createProjectSubResponseFunction]="createProjectSubResponseFunction">
        </app-q-sub-subsequent-process>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried that, but the ngOnChanges does not activate